# Running a specific project when I hit Run in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

In Netbeans I have the option of setting a "Main Project" which basically means if you hit "run", it will automatically execute the main class for that project.

This is convenient for various reasons, for example if you have one project depending on another project and you want to quickly test your changes in your main project.

Does a similar concept exist in eclipse?

Currently, I click on the desired project and then ctrl+F11 to run that project, but it would be convenient if I could just hit F11 or something without the extra action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had that same problem. My workaround is to make eclipse always launch the previously launched application. You can do that in settings, **Run/Debug | Launching**, in the **Launch Operation** section, select:

```
[x] Always launch the previously launched application
```

When you want to launch something different, launch it explicitly, and after that you can relaunch easily with Control F11.

This is very useful for me in practice, as most of the time I work on one thing and relaunch it several times, and rarely need to switch between launchers. (As an aside: in IntelliJ it's nice that I can easily switch between launchers using a simple drop-down list, without manually navigating to the other project/thing I want to switch to.)